# Images not loading correctly when redirecting from a sub-domain to directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Basically, I have a directory `/website.com/` that contains an `index.php`.

What usually happens is that I have an htaccess file that redirects the URL to the index, so something like

```
domain.com/api/
```

Would load

```
domain.com/index.php?uri=api/
```

But now say, instead of having a sub-directory, I want to use a sub-domain, like:

```
api.domain.com
```

Would run:

```
domain.com/index.php?uri=api/
```

---

My current approach *almost* works. My htaccess file looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?uri=api/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?uri=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Which works fine for the URL part. But the problem comes in when I'm trying to load an image.

Basically, instead of loading from the base directory, it's appending the directory onto the URL.

So when I request an image on `api.domain.com/v1/` it's trying to load the image from

```
domain.com/v1/image.png
```

rather than

```
domain.com/image.png
```

---

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I think I found was to use absolute URL's rather than relative ones when including the image (in my CSS).

So rather than

```
background:url(background.png);
```

I used

```
background:url(http://domain.com/background.png);
```

---

Not my ideal solution but it is a workaround. If someone has a better way to solve my problem, I will gladly use.